# Fill matrix A ( Eigen::Matrix2d A) with numbers using loops

Tags: c++, eigen, eigen3

Whenever I try this code I get an Assertion failed !
How can I fill the matrix A using loops ?

```
#include <iostream>
#include "../eigen3/Eigen/Dense"
int main ()
{
 Eigen::Matrix2d A;
 for (int row = 0; row < 5; ++row)
  {
   for (int col = 0; col < 5; ++col)
    {
//     A(row,col)=10;   // ???
    }
  }

}
```

Comment: i should have used  Eigen::MatrixXd A (S, B);
it works now ,,

Answer (score 5):

Well, what you are doing is correct. However, the `Matrix2d` class is, as the name suggests a 2x2 matrix. So you can't increase row / col above 1:

```
 Eigen::Matrix2d A;
 for (int row = 0; row < 2; ++row)
  {
   for (int col = 0; col < 2; ++col)
    {
     A(row,col) = 10;
    }
  }
```

If you want a 5x5 matrix you can use an Xd matrix with a suitable constructor:

```
 Eigen::MatrixXd A(5, 5);
 for (int row = 0; row < 5; ++row)
  {
   for (int col = 0; col < 5; ++col)
    {
     A(row,col) = 10;
    }
  }
```

If the dimensions are known at compile time you could alternatively use an implementation which avoids memory allocation and lives on the stack:

```
 Eigen::Matrix<double, 5, 5> A;
 for (int row = 0; row < 5; ++row)
  {
   for (int col = 0; col < 5; ++col)
    {
     A(row,col) = 10;
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

`Matrix2d` is a typedef to [`Matrix<double, 2, 2>`](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/classEigen_1_1Matrix.html). So it is a 2x2 matrix, and you are acessing columns and rows up to 4, that's why you get `Assertion failed`. You need a `MatrixXd` 5x5:

```
Eigen::MatrixXd A(5, 5);
for (int row = 0; row < 5; ++row)
{
   for (int col = 0; col < 5; ++col)
   {
        A(row,col) = 10;
   }
}
```